# Dynamically initialising a pointer to pointer

Tags: pointers, dynamic, initialization, double

hii,

m initialising a pointer to pointer like this:

// i = the number of items the pointer will point to....

m counting the number of conditions that are present in a sql query and den storing these

conditions in a structure (struct condition)..

so i = no of conditions in the query

// the last item i set it to NULL dats why (i+1) in the malloc statement..

// following is the declaration of COND...

```
               struct condition **COND;
```

// initialisation of COND

```
               SQL_INS->s.COND = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(struct condition *));
```

// after doing this m initialising the individual elements of the variable COND like this

so that each will point to a new structure object

```
               SQL_INS->s.COND[j] = malloc(sizeof(struct condition));
```

i just want to know that is this the right way to do what m doing.. or is htere any better way...

Thanks.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please spell correctly and make your question a little more clear and you won't get answers like this...

```
SQL_INS->s.COND = malloc(((i+1)*sizeof(struct condition *))+(i*sizeof(struct condition)))
struct condition **ptr = SQL_INS->s.COND;
struct condition *cur = (struct condition *)(ptr+i+1);
int j = 0;
for( ; j<i; j++)
  *(ptr+j) = cur++; 
*(ptr+j) = NULL;
```

This keeps all the memory in one block instead of mallocing individual chunks for each struct condition.  I thought it might make your code more readable dats why ii done it :)

Comment: Yup, you are right allocating memory contiguously would be much better for readability.. So what we are doing is correct, by that i mean there isn't another way around this.. Anyways thanks.. it helped indeed.. :)

Comment: Doing this does make it easier to free your memory also.  Just free the one pointer -- free(SQL_INS->.COND) -- and all the structs it points to are vaporized...  just make sure to free any malloced memory inside the structs first.